# How can I get Azure to notify me when a db Copy operation is complete?

Tags: sql-server, azure

Our deployment process involves two db copy procedures, one where we copy the production db to our rc site for rc testing, and then one where we copy the production db to our staging deployment slot for rollback purposes. Both of these can take as long as ten minutes, even though our db is very small. Ah, well.

What I'd like to do is have a way to get notified when a db Copy operation is done. Ideally, I could link this to an SMS alert or email.

I know that Azure has a big Push Notification subsystem but I'm not sure if it can hook the completion of an arbitrary db copy, and if there's a lighterweight solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some information about copy database in this page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff951631.aspx. If you you are using T-SQL you can check the copy process through the query likes `SELECT name, state, state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'DEST_DB'`. So you can keep running this query and send SMS when it shows finished.

Comment: sigh. that sounds like a pain in the butt, but thanks for the information.

Comment: yep, i agree with you but i didn't find any other approaches to get notified when db copy was done. basically this is because the db copy and an async job in azure so no one knows when it will be started and when it's finished. there's a website (i forgot the url) where you can raise and vote features you'd like for azure maybe we can request.